# Multiplying dataframe by float

Tags: python, pandas

Backstory: I have a pandas data frame I need to perform a series of computations on. At the final step, **I need to take each of the rows in the df and multiply them by an array of weights**, with the actual weight value being dependent on the column name.

```py
weightedData = pd.DataFrame()
weightedData['COL NAME0'] = scaledData['COL NAME0']

weights = {'COL NAME1': (2.14, 'E'), 'COL NAME2': (2.14, 'E'), 'COL NAME3': (2.14, 'E'), 'COL NAME4': (2.14, 'E')}

for col in scaledData:
    weightedData[col] = scaledData[col] * weights.get(col, (0.00, 'U'))[0]
```

The `scaledData` df's column names are identical to those listed in the `weights` dictionary as they are populated from the same source (SQL table).

```
                  COL NAME0 COL NAME1  ...    COL NAME3    COL NAME4
0                Alabama     4.099099  ...    2.042345      1.392755
1                 Alaska     1.396396  ...    1.000000      1.000000
2                Arizona     4.189189  ...    2.003257      1.537777
3               Arkansas     2.927928  ...    2.208723      1.007370
4             California     3.378378  ...    1.754930      2.012395
5               Colorado     3.378378  ...    3.282196      2.843435
6            Connecticut     5.000000  ...    1.452587      4.277286
7               Delaware     4.409692  ...    2.134501      1.970434
8   District of Columbia     5.000000  ...    1.000000      1.000000
9                Florida     4.628118  ...    1.806412      2.213038
10               Georgia     4.628118  ...    1.513896      2.748559
11                Hawaii     3.902494  ...    2.891694      3.872309
12                 Idaho     1.090703  ...    2.978469      4.127419
13              Illinois     4.537415  ...    1.242970      1.888353
14               Indiana     4.537415  ...    2.368881      2.307914
15                  Iowa     2.088435  ...    3.298368      3.421122
16                Kansas     2.723356  ...    2.791375      2.160330
17              Kentucky     3.902494  ...    1.692890      4.133744
18             Louisiana     2.451247  ...    1.000000      1.000000
19                 Maine     3.448980  ...    2.535328      5.000000
20              Maryland     5.000000  ...    1.632194      1.046567
21         Massachusetts     5.000000  ...    2.174075      2.503631
22              Michigan     4.804878  ...    1.000000      1.558339
23             Minnesota     4.024390  ...    2.989420      3.733538
24           Mississippi     3.634146  ...    1.000000      3.246507
25              Missouri     4.317073  ...    1.996358      1.000000
26               Montana     1.000000  ...    2.933104      2.140520
27              Nebraska     1.878049  ...    3.103421      2.880362
28                Nevada     4.414634  ...    1.000000      1.000000
29         New Hampshire     5.000000  ...    2.586207      3.877058
30            New Jersey     5.000000  ...    1.293103      3.533832
```

(There are more columns and rows but for simplicity's sake I've included a slice of the df)

However, I've run into an error that seems to be a limitation of Python:

***TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'***

The problem is that my weights must be these already defined float values and it seems incredibly inefficient to iterate over each row + column and apply the weight to each data point individually.

What strategy should I take in order to achieve my goal? It seems as though I should be looking for some sort of workaround but I am currently stuck.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Let me know if more information should be provided. Thanks!

Comment: You can't multiply a sequence by a float, you need to iterate through or map. If you provide a full example we could help further.

Comment: @CMMCD what do you mean by full example? should I include the scaledData df?

Comment: Yes, please include the minimum amount of code needed to recreate the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @CMMCD just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test purpose I created *df* from only a few initial rows of your DataFrame:

```
    COL NAME0  COL NAME1  COL NAME2  COL NAME3  COL NAME4
0     Alabama   4.099099   4.090001   2.042345   1.392755
1      Alaska   1.396396   1.390001   1.000000   1.000000
2     Arizona   4.189189   4.180001   2.003257   1.537777
3    Arkansas   2.927928   2.920001   2.208723   1.007370
4  California   3.378378   3.780001   1.754930   2.012395
```

I changed also slightly *weights* to have different numbers for each column:

```
weights = {'COL NAME1': (2, 'E'), 'COL NAME2': (3, 'E'),
    'COL NAME3': (4, 'E'), 'COL NAME4': (5, 'E')}
```

The first, preparatory step is to selected only the number part (multiplier)
from *weights* (without *'E'*).

```
weights2 = { k: v[0] for k, v in weights.items() }
```

getting:

```
{'COL NAME1': 2, 'COL NAME2': 3, 'COL NAME3': 4, 'COL NAME4': 5}
```

And the whole multiplication can be performed with a **single** instruction:

```
df[[*weights2.keys()]] *= pd.Series(weights2)
```

The result is:

```
    COL NAME0  COL NAME1  COL NAME2  COL NAME3  COL NAME4
0     Alabama   8.198198  12.270003   8.169380   6.963775
1      Alaska   2.792792   4.170003   4.000000   5.000000
2     Arizona   8.378378  12.540003   8.013028   7.688885
3    Arkansas   5.855856   8.760003   8.834892   5.036850
4  California   6.756756  11.340003   7.019720  10.061975
```

As you can see, each column has been multiplied with the proper multiplier.

The multiplication instruction above contains 3 tricks:

1. `[*weights2.keys()]` gives a list of column names to multiply.
2. `pd.Series(weights2)` gives the "multiplication Series" with
   respective column names and multipliers (for each column).
3. Due to `*=* operator, this multiplication is performed in-place.

Comment: would this work if the weights were floats and not ints? thats the issue im currently dealing with

Comment: Of course, you can put also floats. Just add ".1" to each number in weights and repeat the whole procedure. Start from "regeneration" of the source *df*, to "turn back" the first multiplication.